# Can I apply for MS in software engineering in USA from a non CSE background?

Tags: masters

Can I apply for MS in software engineering in USA from a non CSE background? If so, then which universities generally accept with such condition? And how can I make my chances better?

Comment: The answer varies widely based on your previous experiences, what your undergrad was focused in, and so on. If you come from a non technical field you would likely require a large software project or similar to prove competency in the contents.

Comment: Thanks. I'm from Architecture..it was a 5year long course. Im more curious to technology rather than structural thing. So, how will I have to prove myself, as you said about large software project or similar to prove competency.. should I have to make it done before my admission?

Comment: Essentially you will need to prove you have some intermediate knowledge in the field, enough so that you'll be capable of doing research or a project for your thesis. If you can do that you'll have better odds, however I can't recommend any specific schools.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that from my point of view, I see masters' programs as broadly divided into two categories:

The first one contains courses that combine students from two different backgrounds, e.g. biology and IT (bioinformatics), law and IT, finance and IT, etc. In these courses, more introductory modules will be offered, e.g. data structures, programming etc. that are elementary for people with a background in IT but challenging for the others.

The second one contains "advanced" courses, that is people wanting to further specialize on the degree they have obtained. E.g. an "advanced computer science" master will not cover elementary issues (such as databases or computer architecture) but will have more cutting-edge, more advanced topics, closer to concurrent research.

I believe your best bet would be to apply for a master in the first category. I would look for something like "IT for architects", and not for courses with "advanced" in the title.

Comment: Thanks brother, I appreciate your suggestion. Yes I also look for that, found Interactive architecture, Computational architecture (which is combination of both architecture and programming).. but these are only in few universities, like MIT, HARVARD, USA, CMU eta..I thought about these departments, but to get admit to these top listed university is very difficult. I think, in future there will be more universities with this department. But since yet there are limited options of university then except these I didnt find any other option then programming yet, @george

Comment: even from curiosity I talked to CMU admin, they said I need to have some programming language and portfolio where I can show that I understand computational architecture. So, your suggestion is helpful. I was looking for something like that. If you are known to any school where Architecture and IT is offered please share. It'd be very helpful.